# Select multiple items from one dropdown and insert into multiple rows of database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I want to allocate multiple individual courses to students with one row per student-course combination when the data is coming from a multi-select (checkboxes) field on a form.  That is, the data is returned as a single result with multiple courses, and I want to split this up.

Short version: the teacher selects multiple courses from a single dropdown but I want to save data in multiple rows.

Here is my code.

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root');

mysqli_select_db($con,'sss_qr');


    $q="select * from  course_tb ";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$q);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Webslesson Tutorial | Bootstrap Multi Select Dropdown with Checkboxes using Jquery in PHP</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.2/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js"></script>  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <br /><br />
  <div class="container" style="width:600px;">
   <h2 align="center">Bootstrap Multi Select Dropdown with Checkboxes using Jquery in PHP</h2>
   <br /><br />
   <form method="post" id="framework_form">
    <div class="form-group">
     <label>Select which Framework you have knowledge</label>
     <select id="framework" name="framework[]" multiple class="form-control" >
      <?php
        if($result)
        {
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
                $course=$row["course_name"];
                $code=$row["course_code"];
                echo "<option value='$code'>$course</option>";          
            }
        }
        ?>
     </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
   </form>
   <br />
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#framework').multiselect({
  nonSelectedText: 'Select Framework',
  enableFiltering: true,
  enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
  buttonWidth:'400px'
 });

 $('#framework_form').on('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var form_data = $(this).serialize();
  $.ajax({
   url:"insert.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:form_data,
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('#framework option:selected').each(function(){
     $(this).prop('selected', false);
    });
    $('#framework').multiselect('refresh');
    alert(data);
   }
  });
 });


});
</script>
```

and insert.php file

```
<?php 
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "sss_qr");
if(isset($_POST["framework"]))
{   
    $framework = '';
 foreach($_POST["framework"] as $row)
 {
  $framework .= $row . ', ';
 }
 $framework = substr($framework, 0, -2);
 $query = "INSERT INTO allocoursestudent(course_code) VALUES('".$framework."')";
 if(mysqli_query($connect, $query))
 {
  echo 'Data Inserted';
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and ideally should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: I've tried to make the question more clear by first cleaning up the grammar and removing unneeded information.    I  left your code as it is but I do feel you could simplify it a lot to make this a minimal example and using the object-oriented style.  Multiselect is the right term to use when talking about this type of form field.   I also very strongly urge you to follow the security advice in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

so i solve the problem by using this code.

```
<?php 
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "sss_qr");
$course=$_POST['course'];
if($course)
{
    foreach($course as $c)
    {
        $q="INSERT INTO allocoursestudent(course_code) VALUES('".$c."')";
        mysqli_query($con,$q);
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to create a new table that pairs the student and the courses.
Secondly, you need to display students in the form (dropdown menu).

After that, you can do something like this:

```php
<?php 
$connect     = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "sss_qr");

if(isset($_POST["course_code"])){


    $course_code = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["course_code"]);
    $student_id  = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["student_id"]);

    $query = "INSERT INTO new_table_name(course_code, student_id) VALUES";

    for($i=0; $i<count($course_code); $i++){
        $query .= " ('".$course_code[$i] ."', '".$student_id[$i]."'),";
    }

    $query  = substr($query, 0, -1);

    if(mysqli_query($connect, $query)){
        echo 'Data Inserted #'.$i;
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: This creates multiple queries but only runs one of them. It's a flawed approach. It also completely ignores SQL injection problems which are easy to fix. Can you adapt this code to fix those issues?

Comment: That's an improvement, but there's two things to consider here. A) Don't use `mysqli_real_escape_string`, it's not only messy, it's error-prone, instead use placeholder values like `(?,?)` and then `bind_param`. B) Don't use string concatenation for lists, instead add to an array and `join` with `','`. No trimming necessary. C) Even better, prepare the statement once and run it multiple times with different bindings. Prepared statements make statement re-use super fast and easy.